# jQuery 4 divs swap problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been looking for a solution for this problem for 3 days so far and I can't figure out what's wrong. I have 4 `div`s (two in a row, two in column) in a square

```
<div id="menuWrapper">
    <div id="imageSearch">

    </div>
    <div id="usualSearch">

    </div>
    <div id="dataBaseSearch">

    </div>
    <div id="cartoonSearch"></div>

</div>
```

JQuery

```
 $('#usualSearch').click(function () {
    $('#imageSearch').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, '100');
    $('#dataBaseSearch').hide('slide', {direction: 'down'}, '100');
    $('#cartoonSearch').hide('slide', {direction: 'right'}, '100');
    $(this).delay('100').animate({height: '100%'}, 'fast').css({
    'z-index': '2',
    'border-radius': '50px 50px 50px 50px'
    });
    $(this).animate({width: '100%'}, 'fast');
});
```

CSS

```
#imageSearch{
border-radius: 50px 0 0 0;
background-color: #68f431;
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
float: left;
text-align: center;
display: block;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}

#usualSearch{
border-radius: 0 50px 0 0;
background-color: #f46f4d;
float: right;
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
text-align: center;
display: block;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}

#dataBaseSearch{
border-radius: 0 0 0 50px;
background-color: #71c3f4;
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
float: left; !important;
text-align: center;
display: block;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}

#cartoonSearch{
border-radius: 0 0 50px 0;
background-color: #f46fef;
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
float: right;
text-align: center;
display: block;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}
```

This is my problem - I would like these to become `height: 100%` and `width: 100%` within the `#menuWrapper` when clicked, but the other three to stay beneath. My problem is that all other elements jump around and a page is a whole mess. Thanks everybody for the help and if you need additional info just tell me.

Comment: Can you also show your jQuery code? And any associated CSS would also help.

Comment: Maybe, you can add a jsfiddle to reproduce the error.

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle or your exact code...

Comment: Please provide your CSS and Javascript. Also your HTML is missing a </div>.

Comment: why always to down vote if something is wrong..

Comment: Because your question is not producing any value to future visitors that may have the same problem. Please, give as much evidence as possible and if your question evolves, you may get votes back. p.s. do you care about votes or the answer? Don't worry about votes. It's not a contest

Comment: it's not helpful. Just tell what you need else and that's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve your requirements is to add some CSS styles to the elements. I would suggest, adding a class with jQuery, but keep the styles in CSS.

```
#menuWrapper {
   position: relative;
}

#menuWrapper > div.active {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Then, you need to add the class to the element with jQuery.

```
$("#menuWrapper div").click(function() {
   $(this).addClass("active");
}
```

Similar to that, you're then able to remove that class afterwards again.
I would suggest adding another class (like `.element` or so) for every div (instead of `#menuWrapper div`).

The transition/animation can be achieved with CSS3 styles:

```
#menuWrapper > div {
   transition: 0.5s ease all;
}
```

Comment: Forgot to say, that you need to have a ``height: 100%`` in ``.menuWrapper``

Comment: yeah i've figured that out